# Finding the radius of convergence of power series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$$f:(-\rho,\rho)\rightarrow R:x+(\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k*x^{(2k)}}{2k(2k-1)}$$

I tried using the ratio test but a friend of mine said that it only accounts to even numbers and not the odd ones. I quite didnt get this notion, i hope someone will help me understand it.

USING RATIO TEST: $$\lim k\rightarrow\infty $$ I get $$x-x^2$$

so this   $$|x-x^2|<1$$ to get the raio of convergence. Is this correct or i have to use the Root test?

Comment: It is time to give a proper formatting to your questions, my friend. What does it mean $\lim \to \infty$? It is the limit of what? Moreover, how do you get that the series is converging over $|x-x^2|<1$, that is not even a disk? Try differentiating twice you function. After that, it is trivial that $\rho =1$.

Comment: It seems to me you apply the test incorrectly. The ratio of the absolute values of two consecutive terms decreases when $abs (x) \le 1$. If you check this range of values in the original sum, you see that it converges indeed due to the terms in the denominator.

Comment: By expanding the general term into partial fractions, and using the [Gregory series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory's_series) for the arctangent function, in conjunction with the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) for the natural logarithm, we have $$\sum_{k=\color{red}1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x^2)^k}{2k(2k-1)} ~=~ \ln\sqrt{1+x^2}-x~\arctan x.$$

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio How can i diffrentiate it twice like Jack said? If anyone could show me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{x^{2k+2}}{x^{2k}}\frac{2k(2k-1)}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}=x^2\frac{k(2k-1)}{(k+1)(2k+1)}$$

We see that the limit of the ratio is less that one for |x|<1 and is greater than or equal to $1$ otherwise.

Thus, the series converges for $|x|<1$ and diverges for $|x|>1$.

To analyze convergence for $|x|=1$ we see that the series is

$$\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k(2k-1)}$$

which converges absolutely.

Finally, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\text{The series converges for}\,\,|x|\le 1\,\,\text{and diverges for}\,\,|x|>1}$$

Comment: can i do the problem using root test? and for this problem abs(x^2-x)<1 is what i got in the end after limit is taken how can i get what you showed?
thanks in advance.

Comment: @SherlockHomies I'm curious to understand how did you arrive at $x^2-x$ for the ration of $\frac{x^{2(k+1)}}{x^{2k}}=x^2$?  For the root test, one needs to find $\lim_{k\to \infty }|a_k|^{1/k}$.  Here, that would be $$x^2\lim_{k\to \infty}(2k(2k-1))^{-1/k}$$.

Comment: If you saw the lone x standing next to the series. I got -x^2 for the ratio test then i added the x that was outside the whole thing. Even if i get +x^2+x like you did how do i conclude what the radius should be is the question.

Comment: The $xs$ outside the sum does not impact the series; rather, it is completely separate from the series.  For testing convergence, we only look at the terms of the series for large index (e.g., $k$).  The series terms have $x^{2k}$ embedded.

Comment: how would i derive this series twice ? and how would it look like?

Comment: If you take two derivatives, you will get $\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}(-1)^kx^{k-2}$, which you can evaluate using the sum of a geometric series.